# Can I use HHVM side by side with the regular PHP interpreter

Tags: php, hacklang

I'm aware that HHVM can run regular PHP code. What I would like to know is if I can migrate in a way where I serve all files written with `hack` with the `HHVM` and all the files written with PHP via the regular `PHP` interpreter.

I assume this should be possible by using two different file extensions (say `.hh` and `.php`) and then somehow map them two the different interpreters/VM with some nginx setting, no?

Comment: Using CGI, just add a handler for the file type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you asked for nginx, here is an example (untested) Apache CGI configuration:

*(sorry I don't know nginx)*

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    IdleTimeout 3600
    ProcessLifeTime 7200
    MaxProcessCount 64
    DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 8
    IPCConnectTimeout 300
    IPCCommTimeout 7200
    BusyTimeout 300

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    ScriptAlias /php-5.5.10-bin/ /opt/php/5.5.10/bin/
    ScriptAlias /php-5.4.17-bin/ /opt/php/5.4.26/bin/
    ScriptAlias /php-5.3.27-bin/ /opt/php/5.3.28/bin/
    ScriptAlias /php-5.2.17-bin/ /opt/php/5.2.17/bin/

    <Directory "/opt/php">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.hh$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-hhvm
    </FilesMatch>

    ScriptAlias /hhvm-2.4.2-bin/ /opt/hhvm/2.4.2/bin/

    <Directory "/opt/hhvm">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

And the Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hosting@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/deployments/www.example.com/public
    <Directory /var/deployments/www.example.com>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Action application/x-httpd-php /php-5.5.10-bin/php-cgi
        Action application/x-httpd-hhvm /hhvm-2.4.2-bin/hhvm-cgi
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/deployments/$serverName/log/www.example.com.error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/deployments/$serverName/log/www.example.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there anything that speaks against such a setup? It sounds safer as a migration path than just having the HHVM serve your *entire* code base from one moment to the next.

Comment: You're losing a lot of the benefit of Hack if you do this -- that you can seamlessly interoperate and migrate between Hack code and PHP. With HHVM serving everything, PHP code can call into Hack code and vice versa; you can slowly convert to Hack as makes sense. With this setup, your Hack and PHP codebases must be disjoint.