# Is HHVM or PHP5 Zend running?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, hhvm

After some struggle, I finally installed Facebook HipHop Virtual Machine in Ubuntu. It is running under FastCGI (Apache 2.22). Below, the service status:

```
marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:~$ service apache2 status
Apache2 is running (pid 3330).
marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:~$ service hhvm status
 * hhvm is running
marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:~$ sudo service hhvm restart
 * Restarting HHVM FastCGI Daemon hhvm                                   [ OK ] 
marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:~$
```

The same machine has PHP5 module enabled and configured in Apache.

---

### Question:

I want to make sure that I am really rendering `PHP` code using `HHVM` and NOT `Zend Framework`.

All my PHP scripts are running on the webserver. But, when I disable PHP5 module using `sudo a2dismod php5` the web server starts to render `Internal Server Error`.

Does HHVM need PHP5 module enabled to run? Supposedly, since I am using FastCGI, my answer is no. On the other hand, I think that my pages are being rendered by Zend and not HHVM.

What am I missing here? How can I make sure that I am really running HHVM? (in my mind, a clear test is to disable PHP5 module, but, as I said, when I disable, php stops working in the web browser).

If .php is not running with `PHP5 module` disabled does it means that my `HHVM` is not properly configured?

P.S.: The script that I am testing is a default Hello World example: `<?php echo 'Hello World.'; ?>`.

And, It works when I run from command line:

```
marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:/var/www$ sudo hhvm hello_world.php
Hello World.
marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:/var/www$
```

---

**EDIT**

- Apache error.log:

  marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:/var/log/apache2$ cat error.log
  [Wed May 07 14:02:10 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 2627)
  [Wed May 07 14:02:10 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 configured -- resuming normal operations
  [Wed May 07 14:04:52 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/var/www/fastcgi/hhvm.fastcgi": connect() failed
  [Wed May 07 14:04:52 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/fastcgi/hhvm.fastcgi"
  [Wed May 07 14:04:53 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
  marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:/var/log/apache2$

(Apparently, I should have 'hhvm.fastcgi' file. I only have the directory. Is anything wrong here?)

- `/var/www` directory:

  marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l /var/www
  total 20
  drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 May  6 23:45 fastcgi
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root   31 May  6 21:57 hello_world.php
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root  177 May  6 17:47 index.html
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root   21 May  6 17:50 info.php
  -rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 May  6 17:49 info.php~
  drwxr-xr-x 13  997 1001 4096 May  6 18:13 mediawiki-1.22.6
  marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l /var/www/fastcgi/
  total 0
  marcelo@marcelo-VirtualBox:~$

**- FastCGI configuration:**
I added the lines below, as suggested here: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/FastCGI, **at the end of apache2.conf file**. In other words, after all 'mods-enabled' were already loaded.

```
# fastcgi added by M. Sardelich
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    Alias /hhvm.fastcgi /var/www/fastcgi/hhvm.fastcgi
    FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/fastcgi/hhvm.fastcgi -socket /var/run/hhvm/socket -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 300
    <Directory "/var/www/fastcgi">
        <Files "hhvm.fastcgi">
            Order deny,allow
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    AddHandler hhvm-hack-extension .hh
    AddHandler hhvm-php-extension .php

    Action hhvm-hack-extension /hhvm.fastcgi virtual
    Action hhvm-php-extension /hhvm.fastcgi virtual
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So it appears not to be running. Your CGI configuration is probably wrong. Also I wouldn't recommend mixing `mod_php` and CGI PHP/HHVM.

Comment: @Petah, thanks for your prompt response. I can't agree more with the 'mixing' comment. What do you suggest to fix my apache server? I was thinking about completely removing 'libapache2-mod-php5'. Or better to re-install Apache without PHP support? Does HHVM depends on PHP Zend in any manner?

Comment: `a2dismod` should be enough. Zend has nothing to do with it. It is only a framework. Could you post your CGI config? And the error from your logs when you get "Internal Server Error". Also look at my answer here for an example CGI setup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22649371/268074

Comment: @Petah, I edit my question with the information you requested. You comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly noticed (thanks @Petah), my FastCGI config was wrong.

I changed it to the snippet below (from here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HHVM/Vagrant) and everything is working! (add it to your `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf` file)

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    Alias /hhvm.fastcgi /var/www/fastcgi/hhvm.fastcgi
    FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/fastcgi/hhvm.fastcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 300
    <Directory "/var/www/fastcgi">
        <Files "hhvm.fastcgi">
            Order deny,allow
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    AddHandler hhvm-hack-extension .hh
    AddHandler hhvm-php-extension .php

    Action hhvm-hack-extension /hhvm.fastcgi virtual
    Action hhvm-php-extension /hhvm.fastcgi virtual
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6):

To make sure that you are in fact running HHVM, run the following command:

```php
phpinfo();
```

It should produce `HipHop` as the output, instead of the normal php info.

To check for it programmatically, you can use the following [(also mentioned here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777815/how-to-programmatically-check-if-running-on-hhvm):

```php
if (defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
    echo "ruuning HHVM";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I guess the issue is related to FastCGI configuration. From command line it works, and returns HipHop.